# How to fix the misaligned word wise after sideloading AZW3 with Goodreads?

Tags: calibre, kindle-paperwhite, azw

I sideloaded the AZW3 with Goodreads using Calibre. And I see that the downloaded word wise is misaligned.

Is there anyway to fix it manually?

I am using Amazon Kindle Paperwhite 4